# How can I make an absolutely positioned element fill the height of the page in a flex layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two page templates in a Wordpress website, both of which I've tried to use flex CSS to create a sticky footer with a variable height. One of the templates works fine, but the second one has some issues with it.

**The first page template:**

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qohprfwe/7/

As you can see, the content starts below the header and fills the page right down to the footer.

HTML:

```
<header class="header"> </header>

<div class="content"> 
<p>CONTENT STARTS BELOW THE HEADER</p>
</div>

<footer class="footer"> </footer>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
html { 
    height:100%; 
    position:relative;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 

    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column; /* works with row or column */
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
} 

.header {
  height:85px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:green;
}

.content {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1; /* STICKY FOOTER WITH DYNAMIC HEIGHT */
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color:yellow;
}

.footer {  
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom:0;
margin: 0 auto;

height: 85px;
width: 100%; 
background-color:blue;
}
```

**The second page template:**

https://jsfiddle.net/3etssy8m/3/

I have designed the second page template so that the content starts at the very top of the page, underlapping the header. Because I'm using a flex layout to achieve a sticky footer, I have used position:absolute on the content div in order to get it to sit at the top of the page underneath the header. The problem is that the absolute positioning stops the content div from taking up the full height of the page like it does when set to position:relative in the first template. This means that unless I put enough content in my page to fill it up, the content doesn't reach the top as intended and it sits around in the middle of the page. (This doesn't happen in the jsfiddle but it does on my site when I'm using my page builder plugin)

I've tried using height:100%; but this hasn't worked, is there any way I can get the height to fill the page, whilst ensuring that it starts at the very top of the page as it is currently?

HTML:

```
<body>

<header class="header"> </header>

<div class="content"> 

<p>CONTENT STARTS BENEATH THE HEADER.</p>

</div>

<footer class="footer"> </footer>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
html { 
    height:100%; 
    position:relative;
}

body{
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 

    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
 z-index:2;
 height:85px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:green;
opacity:0.5;
}

.content {
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-webkit-flex: 1;
-ms-flex: 1;
flex: 1; /* STICKY FOOTER WITH DYNAMIC HEIGHT */
position:absolute;
top:0px;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background-color:yellow;

}

.footer {   
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom:0;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 85px;
width: 100%;
background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Why you want the content under the header?

Comment: I'll be putting full-width feature pictures under there that underlap the logo and menu links of my website.

Comment: long story short - you can't. Absolutely positioned elements are not a part of the normal flow of the page therefore can't be sized according to their sibling elements (using css only)

Comment: There is a way to do this without using absolute positioning. Your problem is in the logic. You're trying to do something that's not intended for your use.

Comment: Did you ever think about a stycky header?

Comment: @miro – I see, could you give me any advice on how I'd be better of doing this? The height of the footer will change fairly regularly so if there's a way of getting the content div to stop when it reaches the top of the footer, that would be ideal.

Comment: Updated my answer a little, hopefully more clear now

Comment: Did the original WP template use flexbox or is something you're adding on top of that? In general, when you set something to `position:absolute` you're making it behave wildly different than flexbox and the two don't marry well in terms of site layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something like this you are looking for?

This solution also don't use fixed margin etc., all parts is dynamic.

Sample

```css
html, body { 
  margin: 0;
  height:100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  min-height: 85px;
  background-color: green;
  opacity:0.7;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color:yellow;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

footer {   
  height: 85px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>

<div class="content"> 

CONTENT STARTS BENEATH THE HEADER.
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
</div>

<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```

Comment: @Jack1991 Updated my answer, with an absolute position header. Took a look at your page, though it is way to much code to go through. The builder you use also has a lot of built in CSS, so it can very well be that something in it mess with your custom ones, so you need to figure that one out.

Comment: you're probably right, I think there is an issue with the page builder that's doing this. Thank you for your help, I'll send that code to their support team and see if it's fixable.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `top: 0;` and `bottom: 0;` the absolute positioned element will span from the top edge to the bottom edge of its closest non static parent. Play around with those values to style it just way you want it.

Comment: Hi Scorer, thanks for your reply - this unfortunately doesn't solve my problem as I need the content div to reach the top of the footer, rather than the bottom of the page. (Sorry I should have explained this in my question) The reason for this is that the height of the footer will be dynamic and as it gets larger it will overlap my page content.

Comment: you could then try the calc() function

Answer (score 0):

I still don't get precisely what you are trying to do. Like @Claudio said, are you sure it's not sticky header you are after?

If you insist, apply a negative margin to your content that is equal to that of the header height.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/qohprfwe/8/

### Edit for website

Just tested it and it works for me here:

Demo2: http://jsbin.com/jimejipahi/edit?html,output

You need to set the `html` to `100%`.

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#content{
    flex: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `height: 100vh` rather than `html { height: 100% }`?

Without fully understanding what you are trying to achieve based on your question - If you are trying for a flex based sticky footer here is some info -

All you have to do is wrap the vertical sections in a flex container and choose which ones you want to expand. They’ll automatically take up all the available space in their container.

In the example below, the container is set to the height of the window, and the content area is told to expand as needed. (Note: in the vertical direction you need to specify a height for the container. This is different from the horizontal direction, which automatically expands to fit.)

The HTML

```
<body class="Site">
  <header>…</header>
  <main class="Site-content">…</main>
  <footer>…</footer>
</body>
```

The CSS

```
.Site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Site-content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

For more information check out - http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/